# Using .formula to do a vlookup into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like this is pretty simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'd love some help

ws is the worksheet in the activeworkbook

wsc is the worksheet in the workbook where I want to do the vlookup

```
    ws.Cells(2, "BC").Formula = "=vlookup(" & ws.Cells(2, "BB") & "," & wsc.Columns("A:V") & ",4, FALSE)"
```

I'm getting a type mismatch on the wsc.columns("A:V") and I can't figure out why

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: If you insert a formula as text you have to build a string equivalen to that which you would enter manually in the sheet (as you have done for the last bit).

Comment: The right-hand side of a statement that writes a `.Formula` should evaluate to a string that looks exactly like how you would type it in a cell, so `=vlookup(yourvalue,thelookuprange,4,False)`. You need to concatenate in the workbook name and address of those columns; currently you're implicitly trying to concatenate `wsc.Columns("A:V").Value`, which is 2D array. That's an automatic type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SJR and BigBen led me to answer:

```
ws.Cells(2, "BC").Formula = "=vlookup(BB2, '[StudentConcordance.csv]StudentConcordance'!A:V,4, FALSE)"
```